# how to select all anchor tags without navbar anchor tags in a html page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<body>
<nav>
<ul>
<li> <a href="#"> lorem </li>
<li> <a href="#"> lorem </li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div>
<p>ot only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially 
<a href ="#"> lorem </a></p>
</div>
<div>
<p>ot only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially 
<a href ="#"> lorem </a></p>
</div>
<div>
<p>ot only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially 
<a href ="#"> lorem </a></p>
</div>
```

i want to select and style all the anchor tag but only below the nav bar
is it possible in htmt/css jquery or javascript

Comment: Try the child selector (i.e. `$('div > a')` if using jQuery

Comment: Welcome to stackflow. "I want" without demonstrating you've tried isn't going to go down well. Please show us what you've tried and are struggling with. Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular... I would also recommend you take the [tour]

Comment: can you provide better code bcz i can't even format this code.

Comment: First of all, fix your broken HTML - you neglected to close the links inside your nav list items, so the browser will create a different DOM than you intended from this. (There is additional _empty_ links getting created.)

Comment: You can select all links that are descendants of a sibling following the nav element, simply with the selector `nav ~ * a` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator

Answer (score 1):

#### It can be achieved by using the :not() pseudo selector.

The example here matches all a tags except the selectors specified inside the not selector.

```
    a:not(nav a) {
      background-color: orange;
    }
```